# How is $\vec{b}$ loaded in terms of computational basis if we don't know the eigenvectors $\vec{u}_i$ of A?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

In HHL, vector $\vec{b}$ is assumed to be decomposed in the eigenbasis {$u_i$}$_{i=1}^n$ of a Hermitian matrix $A$. However, as we do not calculate explicitly the eigenvectors $u_i$ in course of the algorithm, how do we load $\vec{b}$ into the quantum computer (using amplitude encoding), if we don't even know the $b_i$'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do explicitly calculate $A$'s eigendecomposition of $\vec b$, but *in superposition*.  This is the [quantum phase estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm) portion of [HHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations).

You can provide your initial vector $\vec b$ in the computational basis (e.g., in the $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ basis), and as long as you can simulate $A$ as a [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_simulation) you can perform controlled-versions of this simulation, with the controlling qubits being part of a $k$-qubit ancilla register.  Your initial vector $\vec b$ can be anything and need not be prepared in any eigenbasis of $A$, because the QPE is what does the decomposition.

After doing the Hamiltonian simulations $2^k-1$ times, an inverse-QFT on the $k$ qubits stores the phases (eigenvalues) of $e^{-iAt}$ into the ancilla register, with probability amplitudes given by the amount of overlap to the eigendecomposition of $\vec b$.  This explicitly calculates the eigenvalues of $A$ and “writes” $\vec b$ into this eigenbasis, but *in superposition* and indexed by the phases $|k\rangle$.

The rest of the algorithm is eigenvalue surgery on these phases (and uncomputation and post-selection if needed).

Comment: Ok, so vector $\vec{b}$ can be loaded in the computational basis, the decomposition in the eigenbasis of $A$ happens during the algorithm. Can you direct me to places, where it is explained, what are the options used to load $\vec{b}$? One needs to understand how amplitude encoding is being done, what is the error of this operation, right?

Comment: @wondering I don't know of any one source that could explain how to prepare $\vec b$ as $|b\rangle$ efficiently, but yes that needs to be done and would have error associated with it perhaps, if $|b\rangle$ cannot be prepared error-free.  You could for example adiabatically prepare $|b\rangle$.  I guess the key-words to search for are "state preparation" or something.